# Razor foreach RenderPartial 2 Rows, 5 Across

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, partial-views

I have a MVC page setup to render various partial views I'm calling modules, and within each module I'm trying to render a another partial view of products (based on a model collection) using a Razor foreach loop.  Each module is essentially a different way of displaying the product images, some with details, some just images, etc.  How would I setup the following routine to render the partial view 5 times across, in 2 rows, for a 2hx5w block?

```
@foreach (var product in @Model.CustomizedList.ItemsFound)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Product", product);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to need to add some html and create a either a table or a bootstrap grid.

```
<table>
@int i = 0;
@foreach (var product in @Model.CustomizedList.ItemsFound)
{
    if(i % 5 == 0)
    {
        @:<tr>
    }
    @:<td>
    Html.RenderPartial("_Product", product);
    @:</td>
    if((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
    {
        @:</tr>
    }
    ++i;
}
</table>
```

Comment: Boom goes the dynamite!  Thank you.